# Error generating TypeScript code coverage reports with remap-istanbul + browserify + source maps

Tags: typescript, browserify, source-maps, istanbul, remap-istanbul

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find file: "..\..\..\..\source\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack\_prelude.js"
    at readFile (C:\Users\a0698714\Desktop\CPIC.UI.Web\node_modules\remap-istanbul\lib\remap.js:140:10)
```

When trying to convert the `coverage-remapped.json` into a HTML report.

The following describes my files:

#### /bundle/test/CPIC.test.js

A UMD module named `CPIC.test.js` created with Browserify + Uglify:

```
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{var n;n="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this,n.CPIC=e()}}(function(){return function e(n,t,o){function i(f,r){if(!t[f]){if(!n[f]){var s="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!r&&s)return s(f,!0);if(u)return u(f,!0);var c=new Error("Cannot find module '"+f+"'");throw c.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",c}var d=t[f]={exports:{}};n[f][0].call(d.exports,function(e){var t=n[f][1][e];return i(t?t:e)},d,d.exports,e,n,t,o)}return t[f].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,f=0;f<o.length;f++)i(o[f]);return i}({1:[function(e,n,t){e("./components/engagement.test"),e("./components/questionnaire.test"),e("./components/question.test")},{"./components/engagement.test":2,"./components/question.test":3,"./components/questionnaire.test":4}],2:[function(e,n,t){chai.expect;describe("Engagement Test Suite \n",function(){it("It should ... \n",function(){})})},{}],3:[function(e,n,t){chai.expect;describe("Question Test Suite \n",function(){it("It should ... \n",function(){})})},{}],4:[function(e,n,t){chai.expect;describe("Questionnaire Test Suite \n",function(){it("It should ... \n",function(){})})},{}]},{},[1])(1)});
//# sourceMappingURL=CPIC.test.js.map
```

#### /bundle/test/CPIC.test.js.map

The contents of `CPIC.test.js.map` :

```
{"version":3,"sources":["node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js","test/CPIC.test.ts","CPIC.test.js","test/components/engagement.test.ts","test/components/question.test.ts","test/components/questionnaire.test.ts"],"names":["f","exports","module","define","amd","g","window","global","self","this","CPIC","e","t","n","r","s","o","u","a","require","i","Error","code","l","call","length",1,"./components/engagement.test","./components/question.test","./components/questionnaire.test",2,"chai","expect","describe","it",3,4],"mappings":"CAAA,SAAAA,GAAA,GAAA,gBAAAC,UAAA,mBAAAC,QAAAA,OAAAD,QAAAD,QAAA,IAAA,kBAAAG,SAAAA,OAAAC,IAAAD,UAAAH,OAAA,CAAA,GAAAK,EAAAA,GAAA,mBAAAC,QAAAA,OAAA,mBAAAC,QAAAA,OAAA,mBAAAC,MAAAA,KAAAC,KAAAJ,EAAAK,KAAAV,MAAA,WAAA,MAAA,SAAAW,GAAAC,EAAAC,EAAAC,GAAA,QAAAC,GAAAC,EAAAC,GAAA,IAAAJ,EAAAG,GAAA,CAAA,IAAAJ,EAAAI,GAAA,CAAA,GAAAE,GAAA,kBAAAC,UAAAA,OAAA,KAAAF,GAAAC,EAAA,MAAAA,GAAAF,GAAA,EAAA,IAAAI,EAAA,MAAAA,GAAAJ,GAAA,EAAA,IAAAhB,GAAA,GAAAqB,OAAA,uBAAAL,EAAA,IAAA,MAAAhB,GAAAsB,KAAA,mBAAAtB,EAAA,GAAAuB,GAAAV,EAAAG,IAAAf,WAAAW,GAAAI,GAAA,GAAAQ,KAAAD,EAAAtB,QAAA,SAAAU,GAAA,GAAAE,GAAAD,EAAAI,GAAA,GAAAL,EAAA,OAAAI,GAAAF,EAAAA,EAAAF,IAAAY,EAAAA,EAAAtB,QAAAU,EAAAC,EAAAC,EAAAC,GAAA,MAAAD,GAAAG,GAAAf,QAAA,IAAA,GAAAmB,GAAA,kBAAAD,UAAAA,QAAAH,EAAA,EAAAA,EAAAF,EAAAW,OAAAT,IAAAD,EAAAD,EAAAE,GAAA,OAAAD,KAAAW,GAAA,SAAAP,EAAAjB,EAAAD,GCAAkB,EAAO,gCACPA,EAAO,mCACPA,EAAO,gCCEJQ,+BAA+B,EAAEC,6BAA6B,EAAEC,kCAAkC,IAAIC,GAAG,SAASX,EAAQjB,EAAOD,GCHvH8B,KAAKC,MAIlBC,UAAS,2BAA4B,WAEnCC,GAAG,mBAAoB,qBDInBC,GAAG,SAAShB,EAAQjB,EAAOD,GEVpB8B,KAAKC,MAIlBC,UAAS,yBAA0B,WAEjCC,GAAG,mBAAoB,qBFWnBE,GAAG,SAASjB,EAAQjB,EAAOD,GGjBpB8B,KAAKC,MAIlBC,UAAS,8BAA+B,WAEtCC,GAAG,mBAAoB,0BHkBd,IAAI","file":"CPIC.test.js","sourcesContent":["(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require==\"function\"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error(\"Cannot find module '\"+o+\"'\");throw f.code=\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require==\"function\"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})","import \"./components/engagement.test\";\r\nimport \"./components/questionnaire.test\";\r\nimport \"./components/question.test\";","(function(f){if(typeof exports===\"object\"&&typeof module!==\"undefined\"){module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define===\"function\"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!==\"undefined\"){g=window}else if(typeof global!==\"undefined\"){g=global}else if(typeof self!==\"undefined\"){g=self}else{g=this}g.CPIC = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require==\"function\"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error(\"Cannot find module '\"+o+\"'\");throw f.code=\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require==\"function\"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){\nrequire(\"./components/engagement.test\");\r\nrequire(\"./components/questionnaire.test\");\r\nrequire(\"./components/question.test\");\r\n},{\"./components/engagement.test\":2,\"./components/question.test\":3,\"./components/questionnaire.test\":4}],2:[function(require,module,exports){\n/// <reference path=\"../../src/app/interfaces/interfaces.d.ts\"/>\r\nvar expect = chai.expect;\r\ndescribe('Engagement Test Suite \\n', function () {\r\n    it('It should ... \\n', function () {\r\n    });\r\n});\r\n},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){\n/// <reference path=\"../../src/app/interfaces/interfaces.d.ts\"/>\r\nvar expect = chai.expect;\r\ndescribe('Question Test Suite \\n', function () {\r\n    it('It should ... \\n', function () {\r\n    });\r\n});\r\n},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){\n/// <reference path=\"../../src/app/interfaces/interfaces.d.ts\"/>\r\nvar expect = chai.expect;\r\ndescribe('Questionnaire Test Suite \\n', function () {\r\n    it('It should ... \\n', function () {\r\n    });\r\n});\r\n},{}]},{},[1])(1)\n});\n\n","/// <reference path=\"../../src/app/interfaces/interfaces.d.ts\"/>\r\nvar expect = chai.expect;\r\n\r\nimport { Engagement } from \"../../src/app/components/engagement\";\r\n\r\ndescribe('Engagement Test Suite \\n', () => {\r\n\r\n  it('It should ... \\n', () => {\r\n    //TODO\r\n  });\r\n\r\n});\r\n","/// <reference path=\"../../src/app/interfaces/interfaces.d.ts\"/>\r\nvar expect = chai.expect;\r\n\r\nimport { Question } from \"../../src/app/components/question\";\r\n\r\ndescribe('Question Test Suite \\n', () => {\r\n\r\n  it('It should ... \\n', () => {\r\n    //TODO\r\n  });\r\n\r\n});\r\n","/// <reference path=\"../../src/app/interfaces/interfaces.d.ts\"/>\r\nvar expect = chai.expect;\r\n\r\nimport { Questionnaire } from \"../../src/app/components/questionnaire\";\r\n\r\ndescribe('Questionnaire Test Suite \\n', () => {\r\n\r\n  it('It should ... \\n', () => {\r\n    //TODO\r\n  });\r\n\r\n});\r\n"],"sourceRoot":"/source/"}
```

#### /coverage/PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)/coverage-final.json

The `coverage-final.json` file:

```
{
"C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\CPIC.UI.Web\\bundle\\test\\CPIC.test.js":{"path":"C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\CPIC.UI.Web\\bundle\\test\\CPIC.test.js","s":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":0,"4":1,"5":0,"6":1,"7":1,"8":1,"9":1,"10":5,"11":4,"12":0,"13":0,"14":0,"15":0,"16":0,"17":0,"18":0,"19":4,"20":4,"21":3,"22":3,"23":5,"24":1,"25":1,"26":1,"27":1,"28":1,"29":1,"30":1,"31":1,"32":1,"33":1,"34":1,"35":1,"36":1},"b":{"1":[0,1],"2":[1,0],"3":[0,1],"4":[1,0],"5":[1,0],"6":[0,0],"7":[0,0],"8":[4,1],"9":[0,4],"10":[0,0],"11":[0,0],"12":[0,0],"13":[0,0],"14":[3,0]},"f":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":5,"5":3,"6":1,"7":1,"8":1,"9":1,"10":1,"11":1,"12":1,"13":1,"14":1,"15":1},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"(anonymous_1)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1},"end":{"line":1,"column":12}}},"2":{"name":"(anonymous_2)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":276},"end":{"line":1,"column":286}}},"3":{"name":"e","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":294},"end":{"line":1,"column":311}}},"4":{"name":"i","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":312},"end":{"line":1,"column":327}}},"5":{"name":"(anonymous_5)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":561},"end":{"line":1,"column":572}}},"6":{"name":"(anonymous_6)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":735},"end":{"line":1,"column":750}}},"7":{"name":"(anonymous_7)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":961},"end":{"line":1,"column":976}}},"8":{"name":"(anonymous_8)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1025},"end":{"line":1,"column":1035}}},"9":{"name":"(anonymous_9)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1058},"end":{"line":1,"column":1068}}},"10":{"name":"(anonymous_10)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1082},"end":{"line":1,"column":1097}}},"11":{"name":"(anonymous_11)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1144},"end":{"line":1,"column":1154}}},"12":{"name":"(anonymous_12)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1177},"end":{"line":1,"column":1187}}},"13":{"name":"(anonymous_13)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1201},"end":{"line":1,"column":1216}}},"14":{"name":"(anonymous_14)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1268},"end":{"line":1,"column":1278}}},"15":{"name":"(anonymous_15)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1301},"end":{"line":1,"column":1311}}}},"statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":1,"column":1336}},"2":{"start":{"line":1,"column":13},"end":{"line":1,"column":274}},"3":{"start":{"line":1,"column":69},"end":{"line":1,"column":88}},"4":{"start":{"line":1,"column":93},"end":{"line":1,"column":274}},"5":{"start":{"line":1,"column":134},"end":{"line":1,"column":147}},"6":{"start":{"line":1,"column":152},"end":{"line":1,"column":158}},"7":{"start":{"line":1,"column":158},"end":{"line":1,"column":273}},"8":{"start":{"line":1,"column":287},"end":{"line":1,"column":1333}},"9":{"start":{"line":1,"column":312},"end":{"line":1,"column":648}},"10":{"start":{"line":1,"column":328},"end":{"line":1,"column":628}},"11":{"start":{"line":1,"column":338},"end":{"line":1,"column":514}},"12":{"start":{"line":1,"column":348},"end":{"line":1,"column":390}},"13":{"start":{"line":1,"column":390},"end":{"line":1,"column":414}},"14":{"start":{"line":1,"column":399},"end":{"line":1,"column":414}},"15":{"start":{"line":1,"column":414},"end":{"line":1,"column":434}},"16":{"start":{"line":1,"column":419},"end":{"line":1,"column":434}},"17":{"start":{"line":1,"column":434},"end":{"line":1,"column":480}},"18":{"start":{"line":1,"column":480},"end":{"line":1,"column":513}},"19":{"start":{"line":1,"column":514},"end":{"line":1,"column":538}},"20":{"start":{"line":1,"column":538},"end":{"line":1,"column":627}},"21":{"start":{"line":1,"column":573},"end":{"line":1,"column":590}},"22":{"start":{"line":1,"column":590},"end":{"line":1,"column":605}},"23":{"start":{"line":1,"column":628},"end":{"line":1,"column":647}},"24":{"start":{"line":1,"column":648},"end":{"line":1,"column":721}},"25":{"start":{"line":1,"column":713},"end":{"line":1,"column":721}},"26":{"start":{"line":1,"column":721},"end":{"line":1,"column":729}},"27":{"start":{"line":1,"column":751},"end":{"line":1,"column":853}},"28":{"start":{"line":1,"column":977},"end":{"line":1,"column":989}},"29":{"start":{"line":1,"column":989},"end":{"line":1,"column":1073}},"30":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1036},"end":{"line":1,"column":1071}},"31":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1098},"end":{"line":1,"column":1110}},"32":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1110},"end":{"line":1,"column":1192}},"33":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1155},"end":{"line":1,"column":1190}},"34":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1217},"end":{"line":1,"column":1229}},"35":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1229},"end":{"line":1,"column":1316}},"36":{"start":{"line":1,"column":1279},"end":{"line":1,"column":1314}}},"branchMap":{"1":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":13},"end":{"line":1,"column":13}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":13},"end":{"line":1,"column":13}}]},"2":{"line":1,"type":"binary-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":16},"end":{"line":1,"column":40}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":42},"end":{"line":1,"column":68}}]},"3":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":93},"end":{"line":1,"column":93}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":93},"end":{"line":1,"column":93}}]},"4":{"line":1,"type":"binary-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":96},"end":{"line":1,"column":121}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":123},"end":{"line":1,"column":133}}]},"5":{"line":1,"type":"cond-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":187},"end":{"line":1,"column":193}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":194},"end":{"line":1,"column":262}}]},"6":{"line":1,"type":"cond-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":221},"end":{"line":1,"column":227}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":228},"end":{"line":1,"column":262}}]},"7":{"line":1,"type":"cond-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":253},"end":{"line":1,"column":257}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":258},"end":{"line":1,"column":262}}]},"8":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":328},"end":{"line":1,"column":328}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":328},"end":{"line":1,"column":328}}]},"9":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":338},"end":{"line":1,"column":338}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":338},"end":{"line":1,"column":338}}]},"10":{"line":1,"type":"binary-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":354},"end":{"line":1,"column":380}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":382},"end":{"line":1,"column":389}}]},"11":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":390},"end":{"line":1,"column":390}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":390},"end":{"line":1,"column":390}}]},"12":{"line":1,"type":"binary-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":393},"end":{"line":1,"column":395}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":397},"end":{"line":1,"column":398}}]},"13":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":414},"end":{"line":1,"column":414}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":414},"end":{"line":1,"column":414}}]},"14":{"line":1,"type":"cond-expr","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":601},"end":{"line":1,"column":602}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":603},"end":{"line":1,"column":604}}]}},"l":{"1":5}}}
```

#### /coverage/coverage-remapped/coverage-final.json

The contents of the `coverage-final.json` (remapped) file:

```
{"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\browser-pack\\_prelude.js":{"path":"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\browser-pack\\_prelude.js","statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":1,"column":-1}}},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"(anonymous_1)","line":1,"loc":{"start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":1,"column":-1}}}},"branchMap":{"1":{"line":1,"type":"if","locations":[{"start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":1,"column":-1}},{"start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":1,"column":-1}}]}},"s":{"1":36},"b":{"1":[10,7]},"f":{"1":12},"l":{"1":36}},"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\CPIC.test.js":{"path":"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\CPIC.test.js","statementMap":{},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"(anonymous_7)","line":5,"loc":{"start":{"line":5,"column":108},"end":{"line":5,"column":132}}},"2":{"name":"(anonymous_10)","line":12,"loc":{"start":{"line":12,"column":9},"end":{"line":12,"column":33}}},"3":{"name":"(anonymous_13)","line":19,"loc":{"start":{"line":19,"column":9},"end":{"line":19,"column":33}}}},"branchMap":{},"s":{},"b":{},"f":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1},"l":{}},"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\engagement.test.ts":{"path":"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\engagement.test.ts","statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":2,"column":13},"end":{"line":6,"column":0}},"2":{"start":{"line":6,"column":0},"end":{"line":8,"column":25}},"3":{"start":{"line":8,"column":2},"end":{"line":8,"column":25}}},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"(anonymous_8)","line":6,"loc":{"start":{"line":6,"column":37},"end":{"line":8,"column":1}}},"2":{"name":"(anonymous_9)","line":8,"loc":{"start":{"line":8,"column":25},"end":{"line":12,"column":5}}}},"branchMap":{},"s":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1},"b":{},"f":{"1":1,"2":1},"l":{"2":1,"6":1,"8":1}},"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\question.test.ts":{"path":"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\question.test.ts","statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":2,"column":13},"end":{"line":6,"column":0}},"2":{"start":{"line":6,"column":0},"end":{"line":8,"column":25}},"3":{"start":{"line":8,"column":2},"end":{"line":8,"column":25}}},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"(anonymous_11)","line":6,"loc":{"start":{"line":6,"column":35},"end":{"line":8,"column":1}}},"2":{"name":"(anonymous_12)","line":8,"loc":{"start":{"line":8,"column":25},"end":{"line":19,"column":5}}}},"branchMap":{},"s":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1},"b":{},"f":{"1":1,"2":1},"l":{"2":1,"6":1,"8":1}},"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\questionnaire.test.ts":{"path":"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\questionnaire.test.ts","statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":2,"column":13},"end":{"line":6,"column":0}},"2":{"start":{"line":6,"column":0},"end":{"line":8,"column":25}},"3":{"start":{"line":8,"column":2},"end":{"line":8,"column":25}}},"fnMap":{"1":{"name":"(anonymous_14)","line":6,"loc":{"start":{"line":6,"column":40},"end":{"line":8,"column":1}}},"2":{"name":"(anonymous_15)","line":8,"loc":{"start":{"line":8,"column":25},"end":{"line":26,"column":10}}}},"branchMap":{},"s":{"1":1,"2":1,"3":1},"b":{},"f":{"1":1,"2":1},"l":{"2":1,"6":1,"8":1}},"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\CPIC.test.ts":{"path":"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\CPIC.test.ts","statementMap":{"1":{"start":{"line":1,"column":0},"end":{"line":3,"column":7}}},"fnMap":{},"branchMap":{},"s":{"1":1},"b":{},"f":{},"l":{"1":1}}}
```

The paths in the `/coverage/coverage-remapped/coverage-final.json` file are wrong:

```
 "..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\test\\components\\questionnaire.test.ts"
```

It should be (notice removed `test` folder):

```
"..\\..\\..\\..\\source\\components\\questionnaire.test.ts"
```

I'm not sure about how many parent folders should it go up:

```
"..\\..\\..\\..\\"
```

The bundled file and its source maps work fine but the remap coverage doesn't.

I can guess that is because the source map files don't use absolute or relative paths:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=CPIC.test.js.map
```

But I'm not sure about how to fix it. Any ideas?

### Update

The gulp task that generates the `/coverage/coverage-remapped/coverage-final.json` file:

```
gulp.task("coverage-remap", function () {

  var input  = "coverage/PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0)/coverage-final.json";
  var output = "coverage/coverage-remapped";

  return gulp.src(input)
             .pipe(remapIstanbul())
             .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
});
```

Comment: How are you invoking `remap-istanbul`?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I have added the gulp task

Answer (score 0):

Currently `remap-istanbul` does not support inline source maps and inline source, which is why it is failing with that.  That could be requested as an enhancement.

I think the root of the issue though when not using inline source, is that the URL in the emitted file is being reported as:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=CPIC.test.js.map
```

And that file, which I think is being properly found says that the source is:

```
"node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js"
```

As well as:

```
"test/CPIC.test.ts"
"CPIC.test.js"
"test/components/engagement.test.ts"
"test/components/question.test.ts"
"test/components/questionnaire.test.ts"
```

From where `remap-istanbul` is being run, it will look up the covered file (`C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\CPIC.UI.Web\\bundle\\test\\CPIC.test.js`) and then load the coverage map `CPIC.test.js.map` and then relative to the cwd of the map, try to locate the source files listed in the source map.  It cannot resolve the first one which is causing the error and is basically doing a best endeavor effort (which is mangling the remapped paths as well).

There is the [`basePath` option](https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul#libremap), which allows a "re-basing" of where the sources are.  This may resolve the issue, in a lot of ways you are exceeding the design limitations of `remap-istanbul` where you need complex remapping of files after the generated code has been "moved around" and where there is a few "layers" to unravel to get back to where we started.